# jacoco-maven-plugin not excluding test classes

Tags: jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

Jacoco reports for this project contain line coverage for test classes, despite attempting to exclude tests as below

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*Test.*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*Test.*</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*Test.*</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-check</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <rule implementation="org.jacoco.maven.RuleConfiguration">
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>**/*Test.*</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                                <element>CLASS</element>
                                <limits>
                                    <limit implementation="org.jacoco.report.check.Limit">
                                        <counter>LINE</counter>
                                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                        <minimum>0.94</minimum>
                                    </limit>
                                    <limit implementation="org.jacoco.report.check.Limit">
                                        <counter>BRANCH</counter>
                                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                        <minimum>0.85</minimum>
                                    </limit>
                                </limits>
                            </rule>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The above pom is basically us shotgunning the config with solutions from existing StackOverflow questions, but none of them are working.

Any feedback would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In absence of [Minimal **Complete** Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) one can only guess how your test files are placed in your project and why they are shown in report, because `jacoco-maven-plugin` doesn't show test classes in report by default - here is proof:

for the following `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>example</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

`src/main/java/Example.java`

```
class Example {
    void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

and `src/test/java/ExampleTest.java`

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class ExampleTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        new Example().sayHello();
    }
}
```

execution of

```
mvn clean verify
```

generates following report that as you can see doesn't contain `src/test/java/ExampleTest.java`:

[image: report]

Trying to blindly guess, one can assume that your project has non-standard structure where the above `Example.java` and `ExampleTest.java` reside in the same `src` directory and you have following `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>example</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src</testSourceDirectory>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

then execution of `mvn clean verify` indeed will produce following report that contains `ExampleTest.java`

[image: report]

however in this case following exclusion of `**/*Test.*`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>example</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src</testSourceDirectory>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*Test.*</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

works just fine

[image: report]

Comment: For the record, I am seeing this same problem and do not have a non-standard setup.  My tests and sources are in the standard Maven locations (`src/main` and `src/test`).  I have no `sourceDirectory` or `testSourceDirectory` specified so it should also be using the defaults.  Running Jacoco plugin strictly from the CLI (not via POM file) yields coverage data on the test files.